# How do you convert from the ASCII value to string

Tags: java, string, ascii

I'm stuck with some code here and what I'm trying to do is convert a string into its ASCII value, subtract 30 from it and then convert back to a string.

```
E.g. Enter -  hello
     Convert to - 104 101 108 108 111
     Subtract - 74 71 78 78 81
     display - JGNNQ
```

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class practice {                    
   public static void main (String[] args) {

      String enc = "";
      String encmsg = "";
      String msg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your message");
      int len = msg.length();
      for (int i = 0; i< len ; i++) {
         char cur = msg.charAt(i);
         int val = (int) cur;
         val = val -32;
         enc = "" + val;
         encmsg = encmsg + enc;

      }

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, encmsg);


   }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your current output?

Comment: Java stores text internally as UTF-16, not ASCI. Coercing the `char` into an `int` therefore won't work.

Comment: @BoristheSpider While true that Java char is UTF-16, the first 128 characters of UTF-16 mapping are the same as ASCII.

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple things:

Change  `val = val -32;` to `val = val -30;` to get the proper subtraction you want in the original problem statement.

Next, change

`enc = "" + val;` to `enc = (char)val;`

so that you can convert the value to a proper character.  Before, you were just concatenating it to a string, which won't do any conversion.  You also need to declare `enc` as a `char` at the top of your file.

The full working code should be as follows:

```
    char enc;
    String encmsg = "";
    String msg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your message");
    int len = msg.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char cur = msg.charAt(i);
        int val = (int) cur;
        val = val - 30;
        enc = (char) val;
        encmsg = encmsg + enc;

    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, encmsg);
```

Comment: And since you can actually just do mathematical operations on a char most of the code there is unneeded. The OP can just do `encmsg += (char)(msg.charAt(i) - 30);`.